# Terminator of Recursive Queries

Tags: sql

What is the terminator of Recursive query?
According to:

> The semantics of the recursive execution is as follows:
>      Split the CTE expression into anchor and recursive members.
>      Run the anchor member(s) creating the first invocation or base result set (T0).
>      Run the recursive member(s) with Ti as an input and Ti+1 as an output.
>      Repeat step 3 until an empty set is returned.
>      Return the result set. This is a UNION ALL of T0 to Tn.

Is this correct?

Should the terminator be: "No **new** entry is returned"?

Comment: Sounds correct to me. Recursion stops if there's no row returned, in that case there's no input for the next level. And you might return the same row multiple times (but this will probably lead to endless recursion).

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit long for a comment.

Recursive CTEs are not really "recursive" the way the term is used in other programming languages.  When I think of recursive functions, I think of local variables being saved and a new frame being created for the next function call, and so on and so on.

Instead, "recursive" CTEs are really inductive.  They start at "0" -- the anchor -- and repeatedly apply the recursive member to the new rows of the result set created at each iteration.  Because the inductive step is applied to new rows, it stops when there are no new rows.

So, your interpretation that recursion stops when the empty set is returned is an apt description of what happens.  However, the recursive step is applied only to new rows.

Comment: Thanks very much. That helps a lot. The term "recursive" really confused me.